# get network interface by name not by type c#

Tags: c#

i have code that get network interface name by type (for ex = detecting wireless adapters only)

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /// Detecting Wireless Adaptors Using Linq

        IEnumerable<NetworkInterface> nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(network => network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 && network.Name == "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter"); 

        ////Modified by to select only the active wireless adaptor by using below Linq statement
        ////.Where(network => network.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)

        ////To detect all Ethernet and wireless adaptors you can use below statement 
        ////.Where(network => network.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && (network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet || network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211))

        ///Add Items To Drop Down List
        cmbAdptors.DisplayMember = "Description";
        cmbAdptors.ValueMember= "Id";
        foreach (NetworkInterface item in nics)
        {
           cmbAdptors.Items.Add(item);
        }
        if (cmbAdptors.Items.Count > 0)
            cmbAdptors.SelectedIndex = 0;

    }

    private void cmbAdptors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cmbAdptors.SelectedItem is NetworkInterface)
            {
                slectedNic = cmbAdptors.SelectedItem as NetworkInterface;
                 uniCastIPInfo = null;
                ///Populating IPv4 address
                if (slectedNic != null && slectedNic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses != null)
                {
                    UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection ipInfo = slectedNic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;

                    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation item in ipInfo)
                    {
                        if (item.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            lblIP.Text = item.Address.ToString();
                            uniCastIPInfo = item;                            
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                BandwidthCalculator(uniCastIPInfo, slectedNic);
                wirelssUpdator.Enabled = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            throw;
        }
    }
```

here is the code

but i want that it get network wireless adapter by name

for ex = if adapter has name "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter"

so if i specify that , detect only this adapter if available

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
 IEnumerable<NetworkInterface> nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(network => network.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 && network.Name == "name you want");


foreach(var nIf in nics)
 cmbAdaptors.Items.Add(nIf.Name);
```

Comment: give us more code, not just a line. try my edited answer

Comment: And the problem is that the cmbAdptors displays types instead of names?

Comment: In my comment above i'm asking you, also

try adding before the binding 
cmbAdaptors.DisplayMember = "Name";
cmbAdaptors.ValueMember = "Name";

Comment: i have got the solution that it detects all wireless adaptor and i will add focus on specific adapter property so it will be similar to that i want and i will disable that combobox.

Comment: after the linq query in order to show the names do this

            foreach (var face in nics)
                cmbAdaptors.Items.Add(face.Name);
just tested!

Comment: it also worked with setting the ValueMember / DisplayMember before setting the datasource

Comment: i think u misunderstood my question , i want network interface by name means not their name for ex= Wi-fi , i want network interface name by their adapter name for ex=Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter  , so i want this not for ex no. 1  , your code worked to get for ex no. 1 type , not suitable for 2